# Lightning component detect keystroke in page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

Is there a way to a lightning component detect when the user click a key in the page as whole? My idea is to have the component in the home page and using a shortcut the user can invoke an action even if the component is not focused.

Comment: yes? it is possible... not sure what type of answer you are expecting.

Comment: Adding an event listener is as simple as using `window.addEventListener`. If you're having problems, it might be elsewhere in your code. Can you please include any code you've tried so far, what you've configured, etc? The more details we have, the better we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can implement this feature. You may add the event listener for the whole **window** on a keydown event or even keydown combination. I would prefer adding window event listeners on **render** event. Why?

> Because the **render event** is preferred and easier to use than the
>   alternative of creating a **custom renderer**. Handle this event to
>   perform post-processing on the DOM or react to component rendering or
>   rerendering.

[Handle the render Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_render_handler.htm)

```html
<!--yourComponent.cmp-->
<aura:component>

    <aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onRender}" />

</aura:component>
```

```js
<!--yourComponentController.js-->
({
    onRender: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.applyGlobalKeydownEventListeners(component);
    },
});
```

```js
<!--yourComponentHelper.js-->
({
    applyGlobalKeydownEventListeners: function (component) {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
            if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === 'z') {
                console.log('Ctrl + z is pressed');
            } else if (event.key === 'a') {
                console.log('a is pressed');
            }
            // And so on
        });
    },
});
```

Some additional useful information about **KeyboardEvent.key** 
[MDN Web Docs KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)